# What is the difference between these two ways of taking input from user?

Tags: java, user-input

What is the difference between these two ways of taking input from user?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int num=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

And

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num=sc.nextInt();
```

Here it is assumed that packages io and util are imported accordingly.

Comment: The first method consumes the newline that follows the number, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

These are just two entirely different animals.  When reading from a stream, you're reading simple quantities...characters, bytes, lines.  You then, as you show, have to add additional code to interpret those quantities in some higher level way.

Per the docs for Scanner:

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.

So Scanner adds another level of functionality on top of a stream.  It PARSES the input.  It cuts the incoming data apart and tries to interpret it in various ways that are more complex than just bytes or lines.  Scanner gives you a lot of functionality you'd have to write yourself if you used a simple stream.

To answer your specific question a little more pointedly...do both of the proposed code blocks give you the required result?  If so, and if you aren't going to go on and read anything else from the stream, then maybe using Scanner is overkill.  If you're going to go on and keep reading just integers from the stream, maybe using the raw stream is best.  But if you're next going to want to read a line of text, or a floating point value, or whatever, then Scanner is probably what you want.  Scanner has smarts for dealing with newlines.  You'd have to do that yourself with a basic stream.

Comment: The first method doesn't access a raw stream, it wraps it in a `BufferedReader`, reads a line and parses it. I believe the OP intention was how do these methods of reading a number differ, as they achieve almost the same result.

Comment: Maybe "raw" was the wrong word.  I meant "provides basic, unparsed quantities". - my read was that the OP was asking why to use one vs the other.  That's the question I was taking a shot at answering.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader is

1. Older
2. Large (8 KB)
3. Synchronized (makes it slow)
4. Reads only strings.

While Scanner is

1. New
2. Small buffer (1 KB)
3. Not synchronized
4. Can parse the user input and read an int, short, byte, float, long and double apart from String.

Note that Scanner while making use of regex is slow, which makes BufferedReader faster for reading String.